# Background color of textbox

Tags: xaml, silverlight

I have a textbox inside a datatemplate in Silverlight fram

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ResponseNotificationTemplate">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource TextBlockBase}" Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}, Path=StringsRes.UsageReportID}" TextWrapping="Wrap"
                             Margin="8,7,9,0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" FontWeight="Bold">
                        </TextBlock>
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding UsageReportExtendedResponse.UsageReportUniqueID}" IsReadOnly="True" Margin="0,3,9,0" Background="Gray" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="12.5"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                            <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource TextBlockBase}" Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}, Path=StringsRes.MSReceivedDateLabel}" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="8,0,12,0"></TextBlock>
                            <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource TextBlockBase}" Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}, Path=StringsRes.AliasLabel}" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="8,0,12,5"></TextBlock>
                        </StackPanel>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                            <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource TextBlockBase}" Text="{Binding UsageReportExtendedResponse.MSReceivedDateUTC}" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="10,0,12,0"></TextBlock>
                            <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource TextBlockBase}" Text="{Binding Alias}" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="10,0,12,5"></TextBlock>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource TextBlockBase}" Text="Please use search usage reports to view validation results of &#10;uploaded report." Margin="8,0,12,0"></TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
```

But the background color doesn't change and remains white when the notification pops up.

Can I get any leads on as to why is it happening and what should I do to change the background color. I have even tried defining a style as static resource and applying the style to the textbox but even that doesn't work.

Comment: Try setting IsHiTestVisible to false instead of readonly to true.

Comment: But if I do that, I can't select the text in the textbox. This is a functionality which I need.